# JavaScript display = "none" does not stop the function

Tags: javascript

So I wanted to make a simple counter. When you press "begin" the "word" appears and then you can start pressing the red square and after each press the "number" would increase by 1. If you reach a number that is higher than 5 the "word" would disappear. **The main point is that when the "word" is displayed then you can count but if it is not displayed then you cannot count.** If you don't understand my problem I'll try to explain it in more detail.

```js
var square = document.getElementById("square");
var numb = document.getElementById("number");
var num = 0;
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
var word = document.getElementById("word");

begin.addEventListener("click", function(){
  word.style.display = "block";
  if (word.style.display = "block") {
    square.addEventListener("click", function(){
      num = num + 1;
      numb.innerHTML = num;
      if (num > 5) {
        word.style.display = "none";
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#square{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#number{
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#begin{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#word{
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
<div id="number">0</div>
<div id="begin">begin</div>
<div id="word">word</div>
```

For some reason when I reach 6 and the word disappears the counter still lets you count.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: Not to mention that you set `word.style.display = "block"` and immediately afterwards are trying to check for that exact value. Of course that’s always going to be true.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Op uses `=` instead of `===` here `if (word.style.display = "block")`

Comment: @deceze I still don't understand how to fix my problem.

Comment: @deceze Note that `===` is *usually* better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your if statement to do a comparison check. Right now you are just setting the style to equal block.

```
if (word.style.display == "block")
```

You also need to perform a check for the count value before incrementing it.

```
 if (num > 5) {
    word.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    num = num + 1;
    numb.innerHTML = num;
  }
```

```js
var square = document.getElementById("square");
var numb = document.getElementById("number");
var num = 0;
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
var word = document.getElementById("word");

begin.addEventListener("click", function() {
  word.style.display = "block";
  if (word.style.display == "block") {
    square.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if (num > 5) {
        word.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        num = num + 1;
        numb.innerHTML = num;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#begin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#word {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
<div id="number">0</div>
<div id="begin">begin</div>
<div id="word">word</div>
```